# SwiftUI: Frame of Menu changes when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI View that has a Menu and TexField embedded in a Stack.

What happens is that the frame of the Menu changes when the keyboard appears, as seen in the GIF below. The Menu has a red background, the TextField blue.

When the menu is selected, the frame returns to its previous (and correct) size.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var question = ""        
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Menu("Options") {
                Button("Order Now") {}
                Button("Adjust Order") {}
                Button("Cancel") {}
            }
            .background(.red)
            
            TextField("placeholder", text: $question, axis: .vertical)
                .background(.blue)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

I would expect the Menu to keep its frame size, just like TextField keeps its pre-keyboard appearance size.

How do I keep the frame of the Menu the correct size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jatin's answer, you can define the frame of the label.

I've also added `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` as the label was moving up when clicked with the keyboard open

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var question = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Menu {
                        Button("Order Now") {}
                        Button("Adjust Order") {}
                        Button("Cancel") {}
                    } label: {
                        Text("Options").ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight:20, alignment: .center)
                    .background(.red)
                    
                    TextField("placeholder", text: $question)
                        .background(.blue)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Fascinating. I've copied your code but see a different (and incorrect) result. What versions are you using? I'm on macOS 13.1, Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.2


Edit: in the simulator it looks differently than on my device (iPhone mini). That shouldn't happen. I'll add GIFs later.

Comment: I have it working correctly, as shown in your GIF. Not sure why the exact code you suggested doesn't work using my setup, but the trick seems to be to add an `.ignoreSafeArea(.keyboard)` to the label (as per your code) but don't change anything else.

```
...
} label: {
  Text("Options")
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
}
```

Comment: Thats Interesting. Thanks! I checked my setup, the only difference I found is that I've got iOS 16.1 (with Xcode 14.1). I wonder if the implicit VStack was also affected by the keyboard insert. Anyway, glad you got it fixed!

Comment: I would expect an implicit VStack to be 100% the same as an explicit, but who knows how it works internally.
If you upgrade in the near future, please check if your code behaves differently if you have a chance. It honestly looks like a SwiftUI regression.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you need to add VStack as the parent stack view:

```
    VStack{            //<-----------here as parent
           Spacer()
           HStack {
               Menu("Options") {
                   Button("Order Now") {}
                   Button("Adjust Order") {}
                   Button("Cancel") {}
               }
               .background(.red)
               
               TextField("placeholder", text: $question)
                   .background(.blue)
           }
    }         //<----------here
           .padding()
```

Comment: Thank you, but VStack is implicit, there shouldn't be a need to add that explicitly. Even with the explicit VStack, I'm getting the same result.